# Can I have two ping-pong framebuffers of screen size on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, framebuffer, fbo

I need to have two ping-pong framebuffers in my OpenGL ES app on Android. I  also need them to be of the same size as device screen. Neither depth buffer nor stencil buffer will be attached to them only RGBA8888 color buffer.

I'm planning to use them for adding some Photoshop like blending modes (color burn, overlay, etc.)

Can I afford this on most modern (say above Android 3.0, OpenGL ES 2.0) devices? And if not then Why? And how to determine whenever I can create the prior to their creation?

Comment: Generally speaking, available memory has scaled with screen size. The app limit has increased with each successive release to be able to handle larger and larger bitmaps, and GLES allocations don't count against that limit anyway. Allocating a pair of full-sized frame buffers should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be reasonably safe to assume for devices above Android 3.0, I think they should all be running OpenGLES 2.0?

Your bottle necks will be memory (unlikely to run out here though I would have thought) and complexity of whatever you need to ping pong these buffers for. I ported [this fluid simulation](https://haxiomic.github.io/GPU-Fluid-Experiments/html5/) to Android using OpenGLES 2.0 which relies heavily on ping-ponging frame buffers to perform simulation updates.

I had 6 or so full screen frame buffers on a Samsung Galaxy S4 and Nexus 7 (2012) all of which were created just fine. My problem was that the simulation itself was very complex and these devices just couldn't perform.

I can't imagine memory being an issue for 2 full screen buffers and performance probably will be OK depending on how often you're rendering to them.

Not sure how much this helps as it all depends on your usage.

Can you just check what glFramebufferTexture2D returns when you try to attach it to your FBO in terms of checking if the device can handle it?